# PyOCD package manager is not able to update list

Tags: python, embedded, cmsis, zephyr-rtos

I'm trying to add package stm32wl to Zephyr but Im having problems with pyocd.

```
pyocd pack --install stm32wl
0001491 W No matching devices. Please make sure the pack index is up to date. [pack_cmd]
```

When I try to run the command pyocd pack --update i get a lot of parsing (?) errors:

```
0001287 I Updating pack index... [pack_cmd]
09:19:36 [INFO] Downloaded http://www.keil.com/pack/index.pidx
09:19:36 [INFO] Found 851 Pdsc entries
09:19:36 [WARN] XML error: Expecting </META> found </html>
09:19:37 [WARN] No Core found!
09:19:37 [WARN] No Core found!
09:19:37 [WARN] cannot parse integer from empty string
09:19:37 [WARN] cannot parse integer from empty string
09:19:37 [WARN] cannot parse integer from empty string
09:19:37 [WARN] cannot parse integer from empty string
09:19:37 [WARN] cannot parse integer from empty string
09:19:37 [WARN] cannot parse integer from empty string
09:19:37 [WARN] Support for two parent processors not implemented!
09:19:37 [WARN] XML error: Expecting </P> found </BODY>
09:19:37 [WARN] XML error: Expecting </P> found </BODY>
09:19:01 [WARN] No Core found!
09:19:01 [WARN] Support for two parent processors not implemented!
09:19:01 [WARN] No Core found!
09:19:01 [WARN] No Core found!
```

My tools are up to date:

```
pyocd --version
0.34.3

python --version
Python 3.11.1
```